# Problems adding Any-Element to dynamically created XSD-Schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I just wanna add an Any-element node to an existing XSD-Schema created by this code particle:

```
    private void CreateSchema()
    {
        //This function returns the XML Schema definition of a XML Element by using the Generation function of a Dataset

        XmlSchemaInference x_scheme = new XmlSchemaInference();
        this.XsDSchemaSet = x_scheme.InferSchema(this.myXmlElement.CreateReader());

        this.XsDSchemaSet.Compile();;
    }
```

After I created the XSD-Schemaset some parts have to be modified. The following code sets the Min- and max-Occurs attributes of existing elements which also works fine. 
After modification of the attributes I also have to add an Element of type XmlSchemaElement to the Items-collection of the XmlSchemaSequence like you see in the few lines above the end of the sample code. That does not work. While debugging i can see the element within the Items-collection, but after Reprocessing & recompilation of the Schemaset the modified attributes are set pretty well, but the generated Any-element is not present like you see in the MessageBox of final result. Could anybody help?

```
  private bool ModifyXsdElement(XmlSchemaElement element, XElement myXmlElement)
    {
        // this function modifies the occurance min an max of the child elements

        XmlSchemaSimpleType simpleType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaSimpleType;
        if (simpleType != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Function XsdModifyElement: Error - Simple Type!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;
            if (complexType != null) //This is a complexType object
            {
                if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
                {
                    //todo: anything if there are attributes
                }
                bool typeMatch = false;
                XmlSchemaSequence sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;
                if (sequence != null)
                {
                    typeMatch = true;
                    string fixedValue = string.Empty;
                    XmlSchemaElement el = new XmlSchemaElement();
                    foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Child Element: " + childElement.Name);
                        int iOccCtr = GetNoOfXmlChildElements(childElement.Name, myXmlElement);
                        childElement.MinOccurs = iOccCtr;
                        childElement.MaxOccurs = iOccCtr;
                        childElement.MinOccursString = iOccCtr.ToString();
                        childElement.MaxOccursString = iOccCtr.ToString();
                        if (FixedValues.TryGetValue(childElement.Name.ToString(), out fixedValue))
                            childElement.FixedValue = fixedValue;
                        el = childElement;
                    }

                    //Add any element
                    XmlSchemaAny anyElement = new XmlSchemaAny();
                    anyElement.MinOccurs = 0;
                    anyElement.MaxOccurs = 1;
                    anyElement.ProcessContents = XmlSchemaContentProcessing.Lax;
                    anyElement.Parent = sequence;
                    sequence.Items.Add(anyElement);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The final result of the compiled Schema looks like that:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault=\"unqualified\" elementFormDefault=\"unqualified\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
    <xs:element name=\"STEP\">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>    
                <xs:element minOccurs=\"1\" maxOccurs=\"1\" fixed=\"0002\" name=\"LFDNR\" type=\"xs:unsignedByte\" />      
                <xs:element minOccurs=\"1\" maxOccurs=\"1\" name=\"FUNKTIONSNUMMER\" />        
                <xs:element minOccurs=\"1\" maxOccurs=\"1\" fixed=\"Firmwareinformationen lesen\" name=\"FUNKTIONSNAME\" type=\"xs:string\" />    
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks for your help! 
Br Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to your use of a post compilation property. As the help has it:

> The particle for the content type. The post-compilation value of the ContentType particle.

In general, one hint in using .NET's SOM API is to look for properties that have a setter as well. "hint" since some of the properties are both: post compilation, and user configurable.

If your complex type's definition has an explicit content model (extension or restriction), then you need to use the [XmlSchemaComplexType.ContentModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype.contentmodel(v=vs.110).aspx). If it's an [XmlSchemaComplexContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplexcontent(v=vs.110).aspx), navigate its [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplexcontent.content(v=vs.110).aspx) property (one of XmlSchemaComplexContentRestriction or XmlSchemaComplexContentExtension); each of these types have a Particle property, which is the one you can modify.

Otherwise, if there's no content model, simply access the [XmlSchemaComplexType.Particle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype.particle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Petru. I did not care about usage of post and pre-compilation properties!

Answer (score 1):

ContentTypeParticle is a post-compiled property. Only some attributes like min-/max-Occurs can be modified. To add new nodes, like the any node in this case, the Particle-property must be modified. After reprocessing of the schema and recompilation of the SchemaSet the new element will be added to the post-compiled ContentTypeParticle. 
Thanks to @Petru-Gardea